# How to replace character based on specific condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a message like this.

`var str = "My name is Amit.<br>This <i>is</i> a invalide tag<test>";`

While showing this message in the browser I want that the `<br>` tag should show a line break , but all other tags should be escaped, I
mean other tags like `<i> , <test>` should appear as it is. So I want the final output to be,

```
`My name is Amit.
This <i>is</i> a invalide tag<test>`
```

So I tried with this logic.

```
var str = "My name is Amit.<br>This is a invalide tag<test>";
var htmlEncodedNote = str.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
htmlEncodedNote = htmlEncodedNote.replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
htmlEncodedNote = htmlEncodedNote.replace(/&amp/g,"&amp;");
```

But it shows the `<br>` tag also in the browser. Could anyone please help me to create regular expression that will replace all angular brackets except for `<br>`

Here is the sample code.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("tt");
var str = "My name is Amit.<br>This is a invalide tag<test>";
var htmlEncodedNote = str.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
htmlEncodedNote = htmlEncodedNote.replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
htmlEncodedNote = htmlEncodedNote.replace(/&amp/g,"&amp;");

container.innerHTML = htmlEncodedNote;
```

```html
<div id="tt"></div>
```

> `

Comment: `htmlEncodedNote.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/g, '\n');`

Comment: Its not working . `<test>` does not appears even `<br>` is also not working there is no line break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample code, 
add this line before `container.innerHTML = htmlEncodedNote;`

```
htmlEncodedNote = htmlEncodedNote.replace(/&lt;br&gt;/g,"<br>");
```

Comment: and there also a possiblity of space between `br` and `/` So I think this will work best `/&lt;br\s*\/?&gt;/g`

Answer (score 1):

I'm very confused on what you want to do but here's what I think you want:

JavaScript is *not* HTML. You don't need to escape the text, use:

```
var str = "My name is Amit.<br>This <i>is</i> a invalide tag<test>";
var replacedNode = str.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/g, '\n');
```

Replaced node will be `str`, but `<br>` have become newlines. To HTML encode it:

```
var htmlEscapedString = document.createTextNode(replacedNode),
    elem              = document.getElementById("tt");
while(elem.firstChild) elem.removeChild(elem.firstChild);
elem.appendChild(htmlEscapedString);
```

---

```js
var str = "My name is Amit.<br>This <i>is</i> a invalid tag<test>";

var htmlEscapedString = document.createTextNode(str),
    elem              = document.getElementById("tt"),
    temp = document.createElement('div'); temp.appendChild(htmlEscapedString);
while(elem.firstChild) elem.removeChild(elem.firstChild);
htmlEscapedString = temp.innerHTML.replace(/&lt;br\s*\/?\s*&gt;/g, '<br/>');
elem.innerHTML = htmlEscapedString;
```

```html
<div id="tt"></div>
```

Comment: But see the line break is not appearing . I want the line break after "My name is Amit."

Comment: Still there is no line break after the first line.

Comment: @user3427540 Updated  once again!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var str = "My name is Amit.<br>This is a invalide tag<test>";
one = str.split("<br>");
var htmlEncodedNote = one[1].replace(/</g,"&lt;");
htmlEncodedNote = htmlEncodedNote.replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
htmlEncodedNote = htmlEncodedNote.replace(/&amp/g,"&amp;");

container.innerHTML = one[0]+"<br>"+htmlEncodedNote;
```

Checkout this [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/yahupa/1/)

---

**For multiple** `<br>` Checkout this [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/yahupa/2/) and check the following code:

```
var container = document.getElementById("tt");
var str = "My name is Amit.<br>This is a invalide tag<test><br>Another Line<br>Third Line<Fox>";
htmlEncodedNote = [];
out = "";
one = str.split("<br>");
alert(one.length)
for (i = 1; i < one.length; i++)
{
 htmlEncodedNote[i] = one[i].replace(/</g,"&lt;");
htmlEncodedNote[i] = htmlEncodedNote[i].replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
htmlEncodedNote[i] =  htmlEncodedNote[i].replace(/&amp/g,"&amp;");
out += htmlEncodedNote[i]+"<br>";
}

container.innerHTML = one[0]+"<br>"+out;
```

Comment: What if OP has multiple `<br>`?

Comment: Yes multiple `<br>` is possible.

Comment: He does not tell about that condition. However, in this case, a `for` loop for the array named `one` stating from the second element will perform the task. @vihan1086

Answer (score 0):

It is the not best way, but you can do it with this way..

```
var container = document.getElementById("tt");
var str = "My name is Amit.<br>This is a invalide tag<test>";
var str = str.replace("<br>", "**AA**");//you may change 
var htmlEncodedNote = str.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
htmlEncodedNote = htmlEncodedNote.replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
htmlEncodedNote = htmlEncodedNote.replace(/&amp/g,"&amp;");
var htmlEncodedNote = htmlEncodedNote.replace("**AA**", "<br>");

container.innerHTML = htmlEncodedNote;
```

Answer (score -1):

This little function has never done me wrong for replacing `<br> or <br />` with '\n' aka line break:

```
var str = document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('mytextarea').innerHTML = str.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, "\n");
```